# Is there any way I can make my python number guesser more efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have a game where you have to guess a number the code picks at random (I was looking at project ideas), before taking a look at the answer I want to know if there is a more efficient to store the if's? I do think there might be a way to merge them into one single block and delete the others.

```
def guess(x):  # this is a number generator
    ran_num = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = int(input('type number guess from 1 to {} '.format(x)))
    attempt_num = 4
    if attempt_num < 1:
        print('game over')
        exit()
    elif guess < ran_num:
        (print('your guess was a bit low'))
    elif guess > ran_num:
        print('your guess was all too high')
        
    while guess != ran_num:
        guess = int(input('oh no, your number is incorrect, please type that again, you gots {} attempts left '.format(attempt_num)))
        attempt_num -= 1
        if attempt_num < 1:
            print('game over')
            exit()
        elif guess < ran_num:
            (print('your guess was a bit low'))
        elif guess > ran_num:
            print('your guess was all too high')

    if guess == ran_num:
        print("success")
guess(5)
```

Comment: You can maybe merge the two times you are using if-else:
once outside while-loop, once inside while-loop

Comment: put the block into a function and call the function passing in `guess, attempt_num, ran_num`

Comment: `if attempt_num < 1:` can never be true at the beginning of the function, since you just assigned `attempt_num = 4` on the line before.

Comment: As a general style principle, try to come up with better names for things, so as to avoid reusing them. While it doesn't cause a problem here, using `guess` as a local variable within the `guess` function means that recursion is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some repeated code, so it would be a good idea to just put the `if-else` blocks into a function, this will simplify your code.

I added a `check_guess` function, and made `ATTEMPT_NUM` global so we can reference it and update it in both functions.

```
import random

ATTEMPT_NUM = 4

def guess(x):  # this is a number generator
    global ATTEMPT_NUM
    ran_num = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = int(input('type number guess from 1 to {} '.format(x)))
    check_guess(ran_num, guess)
        
    while guess != ran_num:
        guess = int(input('oh no, your number is incorrect, please type that again, you gots {} attempts left '.format(ATTEMPT_NUM)))
        ATTEMPT_NUM -= 1
        check_guess(ran_num, guess)

    if guess == ran_num:
        print("success")

def check_guess(ran_num, guess):
    global ATTEMPT_NUM
    if ATTEMPT_NUM < 1:
        print('game over')
        exit()
    elif guess < ran_num:
        (print('your guess was a bit low'))
    elif guess > ran_num:
        print('your guess was all too high')

guess(5)
```

Comment: what does global do on attempt_num?

Comment: @San Kool the `global` keyword allows you to modify a global scoped variable in a local context

Answer (score 2):

Just ask for the guess inside the loop. You can use a `for` loop to iterate 4 times.

```
def guess(x):  # this is a number generator
    ran_num = random.randint(1, x)

    for attempt_num in range(4, 0, -1):
        guess = int(input('type number guess from 1 to {}, you gots {} attempts left '.format(x, attempt_num)))
        elif guess < ran_num:
            (print('your guess was a bit low'))
        elif guess > ran_num:
            print('your guess was all too high')
        else:
            print("success")
            break
    else:
        print('game over')

guess(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this attempt. x was the max random number you could get, right? Combine everything in an infinite loop that only breaks after you win or you put wrong all the numbers.

```
def guess(x):
    attempt_num = 5
    ran_num = random.randint(1, x)
    while True:
        guess = int(input('type number guess from 1 to {} '.format(x)))
        if guess == ran_num:
            print ("congrats")
            break
        elif guess < ran_num:
            (print('your guess was a bit low'))
            attempt_num = attempt_num -1
        elif guess > ran_num:
            print('your guess was all too high')
            attempt_num = attempt_num -1
            print (attempt_num)
        
        if attempt_num == 0:
            print ("game over")
            break
```

It wouldn't hurt if you do a small check in the input to avoid the user putting anything else than a number, though.